# When i add custom profile to package its show N/A . How to add custom profile in managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-profile

When i add custom profile to package its show N/A . Also when this package is installed in another org (testing org), It is not displayed at all to link profile settings to any profile

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure it out but here's the solution:

IN YOUR DE ORG:

1. Clone Standard Platform User profile (because is the one that has the Salesforce Platform license) an name it something meaningful like MyApp_Profile
2. Customize MyApp_Profile to match your desired access level for the users that will test or use your app
3. Add custom profile settings MyApp_Profile to the package
4. Go ahead an finish the package

IN THE TEST_ORG (OR YOUR_CUSTOMER_ORG):

5. Pre-create a profile by cloning the Standard Platform User profile and name it something meaningful like MyApp_TestProfile
6. Assign MyApp_TestProfile to a user
7. Install the package and on Step 2 (Choose security level) of  the wizard you have to select the third option (Select security settings)
8. Under "Customize security" section make sure the MyApp_TestProfile (created on step 5) has the MyApp_Profile assigned (created on step 1)
9. Finish the Package installation
10. Log to the test or customer org with the user that has the MyApp_TestProfile assigned and choose your App from top right menu.

I hope this solves your issue too!

Comment: When I add my profile setting in package it gives N/A. Also when I install package on test instance It does not show my profile settings at all.  Is there some settings to add profile settings ?